# Running Express Node.js NOT on localhost port?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Apologies in advance since I'm very new to this and don't know much about backend.

I've created a React web app and need to connect it to a MySQL db, so I've decided to use Express Node.js. However, in all the tutorials I have found online, they all connect to localhost, which I run on my Mac terminal. It works, but when I exit out of terminal, it stops working so I was wondering if there was a way for me to do it without using my ports.

Here's my code for reference:

```
const express= require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const cors=require('cors');

const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

var mysql = require('mysql');
 
create a connection variable with the required details
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "",
    user: "", 
    password: "",
    database: "" 
});
 
make to connection to the database.
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // if connection is successful
    console.log('connection successful');
});

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.json('OK');
});

app.post('/', (req,res) => {
    var { ParticipantID } = req.body;
    var records = [[req.body.ParticipantID]];

    if (records[0][0] != null) {
        con.query("INSERT into Survey (ParticipantID) VALUES ?", [records], function(err, res, fields) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
    res.json('Form recieved');
});

app.listen(3001,()=>console.log("Port 3001"));
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the port since this is the medium of communication your application server uses.
And yes it is a valid behaviour that, if you kill your terminal,
That means you are stopping your application server forcefully which in turn stops communicating via port 3001.
I hope I have clarified your doubt !

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful :) So is there a way for me to have it keep running without it stopping? I can't have my computer on all the time but I still want my code to be able to push to my database while I'm away

Comment: :) for that you need the dedicated service probably, a cloud service, which will run 24x7 your application once you deploy your code there. For now , you need to keep the browser running in local, to let the application server communicate to 3001 port.